# What's the difference between "...rise by 2 degrees" and "...rise 2 degrees"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions

The following two sentences:

> The temperature will rise by 2 degrees.
> The temperature will rise 2 degrees.

Are both correct?

Is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: No - including ***by*** makes no difference whatsoever to the meaning. We can even throw in another preposition: [*the temperature close to the ground level will **rise up by** 2-3 degrees.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22will+rise+up+by+2%22) The meaning is unchanged regardless of whether we include neither, either, or both of those prepositions.

Comment: ...but the meaning of my example *would* change if we reverse ***up + by*** and add the third preposition ***to***, giving *the temperature will rise **by up to** 2 degrees.*

Answer (score 1):

Both constructions, with and without
*by*, are commonly used.

[Cambridge Dictionary illustrates](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rise):

> Gold bullion for delivery in December **rose** $1.20 an ounce to $400 an ounce.

> Retail sales volume **rose by** 7.2% in the 12 months to June.

[Collins Dictionary illustrates](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rise):

> 9. VERB B2
>    Exports in June **rose** 1.5% to a record $30.91 billion.

As what @FumbleFingers said, they mean the same.